# Is "even" a choice in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

I would appreciate your help.

> He is not strong at all. He would not even lift me.

I would like to express that he would not even lift me, let alone heavier stuff.

Answer (score 7):

*Even* is fine, but you probably want *could* instead of *would* to denote ability.  *Would* suggests willingness.

> He is not strong at all.  He *could* not even lift me.

Comment: Right. A good source for the usage of _let alone_ is [Fillmore, Kay, and O'Connor 1988](http://lingo.stanford.edu/sag/papers/fillmore%2B88.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with 'cornbread', the word you should use is **could** instead of **would**. But if you are talking informally, you could also use **cannot**.

> He is not strong at all. He **cannot** even lift me.

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence is fine, but you might like to consider *He could not lift even me*, which carries the implication that lifting other things would certainly be beyond him. *He could not even lift me* might have a different connotation, that he certainly could not carry you any distance.  But it's a minor point.

Comment: +1 Not a minor point at all; this conveys the OP's intentions best.